# How to find $g(t)$ given a triangular pulse as a convolution of function $g(t)$ with $g(t)$?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, convolution

Let there be a triangular pulse $f(t)$ in time domain (as shown in  figure). The triangular pulse can be expressed as a convolution of a function $g(t)$ i.e. $f(t)=(g*g)(t)$. Find $g(t)$.

[image]

**my attempt**:

i used property of similar triangle
$$\frac{f(t)}{a-|t|}=\frac{1}{a}$$
$$f(t)=1-\frac{|t|}{a}$$
$$\therefore f(t)=\begin{cases}{ 1-\frac{|t|}{a}\  \text{if}\ |t|\le a \\ 0 \ \text{if}\ |t|>a} \end{cases}$$

$$f(t)=(g*g)(t)$$
i take fourier transform
$$F(f(t))=F(g(t))F(g(t))$$$$F(f(t))=(F(g(t)))^2$$
I found $F(f(t))=a sinc^2(a\omega/2)$
so i get
$$F(g(t))=\sqrt{F(f(t))}=\sqrt{a} sinc (a\omega /2)$$
$$g(t)=F^{-1}(\sqrt{a} sinc (a\omega /2))$$

I got stuck here and I am not sure if everything correct upto this point. Can someone please help me to get $g(t)$.

thank you

Comment: Hint: $F(h * u) = F(h)F(u)$, where $F(h)$ is the fourier transform of $h$

Comment: Do you mean $F((g*g)(t))=F(g(t))F(g(t))$? Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Maybe you would like to check this post out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940221/convolution-of-two-square-pulses-and-the-fourier-transform-of-a-triangular-pulse